# unable to do switchover in postgresql9.0

Tags: linux, postgresql

I m trying to do switchover in postgresql. That means making standby server as master and master as standby server. But it's writing these lines in log file...

```
2011-06-24 09:15:45 ETC/GMT LOG:  unexpected timeline ID 1 in log file 0, segment 5, offset 0
cp: cannot stat `/data/PostgreSQL/archive/000000090000000000000005': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The slave should be able to access archive logs on the master. In the recovery.conf file, the restore_command should locate where the master's archive logs are stored. On the master postgresql.conf: archive_mode should be on and the archive_command (where you put archives) should be accessible from the slave. Also in the slave recovery.conf file you should write your trigger_file which can be located anywhere on the slave. This file is just to trigger.no data in it.